# Scala syntax description

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

i'm looking for any resourse with scala syntax description.
for example, right now i tried to understand what doing this function:

```
reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
```

but i don't able to find what does mean `++` character...
i looked at:
http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/
but it doesn't answer on my question.
possobly someone could advice good resource like "underastanding scala" with good detailed examples

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`++` is just a method name in Scala, like `+` or `*`. You can find a list of all standard library methods starting with non-letters at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#index.index-_.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@alexey-romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov) answer

In general ++ is used for generating a new data structure.

We can use it in following forms(with example) :-

### 1. ++

++ is used to yield a new data structure.

Ex :-

```
val digits2=Map("One"  -> 1,"Two"  -> 2)
val digits = Map[String,Int]() ++ digits2 

digits: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(One -> 1, Two -> 2)
```

**OR**

Note:- Below digits4's map is having a key **One** with a value  **5**

```
val digits4=Map("One"  -> 5,"Three"-> 3,"Four"  -> 4)
val Combined1 = digits2 ++digits4

Combined1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(One -> 5, Two -> 2, Three -> 3, Four -> 4)
```

### 2. ++:

This operator does same as above `++` does. When used on two operands.

```
val Combined2 = digits2 ++:digits4
Combined2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(One -> 5, Two -> 2, Three -> 3, Four -> 4)
```

### 3. ++= and ++=:

they do similar operations on other data types defined in http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#index.index-_.

```
val buf = new StringBuilder
buf += 'a'
buf ++= "bcdef"
println("buf : "+buf)
```

results
buf : abcdef

```
val buf1 = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
buf1 +="a"
val buf2 = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
buf2 +="bcde"
val buf3 = buf1 ++=: buf2
println("buf3 = "+buf3)
```

results :- buf3 = ArrayBuffer(a, bcde)